# Can you rewrite an already written Joomla SEF url through .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

I have a Joomla site with SEF turned on.

The login page of my site is *www.example.com/login*

A third party requires I have the page URL be: *www.example.com/memberlogin.cfm*

I tried to use:

`RewriteRule ^(/golferlogin.cfm)?$ login [L]`

It wont work, makes the page come up with a *Error 500*...

Anyone have any ideas for a fix to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try tp place this in root folder `.htaccess`:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRUle ^golferlogin\.cfm$ /login [L]
```

The above will process requests to `/golferlogin.cfm` in the same way as requests to `/login`.
Basically there is extra slash `/` in your regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kamil, i added it and it doesn't seem to be working, still shows /login in the URL..

Comment: It does something different - it does the same for `/golferlogin.cfm` as for `/login`... basically this rule creates something like *alias* for `/login` action. It's not supposed to change the `/login` to anything else... I understood your question as "how to make other URL act as the login page". You need something else?